# React Vite + React Router Dom - Scroll bar missing after clicking on NavLink

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router-dom, vite, parallax

I need some help... I'm building a multi-page B&B app using React (Vite) and React Router Dom. I'm also using React Query, React Scroll Parallax, Material UI and Redux Toolkit.

**Here's my problem:**
If I click on most of the NavLink components in my navbar, the url changes and the page routes correctly, BUT, the scroll bar is missing and I can't scroll the page. However if I manually refresh the page in the browser, the scroll bar is back again and everything works as expected. Also, this doesn't happen on all of my NavLinks, only some of them. For instance, the Login and Register NavLinks render with the scrollbar, as well as my About page inside my Footer component. I have checked to see if there are any differences in the structuring of the Routes or the NavLink components, but I couldn't see any differences.

I have tried automatically refreshing the page once with useEffect, but I can't get it to refresh only once, it keeps refreshing in a loop, so I removed it...

**ANY HELP WOULD BE HIGHLY APPRECIATED...**

**Here is my App.jsx:**

```
function App() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />

      <div id="back-to-top-anchor" style={{ minHeight: "0" }}></div>

      <ParallaxProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
          <Route
            path="all-listings"
            element={<AllListings initialState={initialState} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="listing/:listingId"
            element={<Listing initialState={initialState} />}
          />
          <Route path="how-it-works" element={<HowItWorks />} />
          <Route path="contact-us" element={<ContactUs />} />
          <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />

          <Route path="my-listings" element={<MyListings />} />
        </Routes>
      </ParallaxProvider>

      <ShapeDivider color="#ffffff">
        <Footer />
      </ShapeDivider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**And here is my menu inside NavBar.jsx:**

````
  const menu = (
    <>
      <div
        onClick={() => {
          setMobileOpen(true);
        }}
        className={classes.navbarSmallMenu}
      >
        <NavLink
          className={({ isActive }) =>
            isActive ? classes.activeNavbarStyle : undefined
          }
          to="/"
        >
          Home
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink
          className={({ isActive }) =>
            isActive ? classes.activeNavbarStyle : undefined
          }
          to="all-listings"
        >
          All Listings
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink
          className={({ isActive }) =>
            isActive ? classes.activeNavbarStyle : undefined
          }
          to="how-it-works"
        >
          How It Works
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink
          className={({ isActive }) =>
            isActive ? classes.activeNavbarStyle : undefined
          }
          to="contact-us"
        >
          Contact Us
        </NavLink>
      </div>

      <div className={classes.navbarSmallMenu}>
        {isUserLoggedIn ? (
          <>
            <IconButton
              id="profile-avatar"
              onClick={handleOpenUserMenu}
              sx={{ p: 0 }}
            >
              <Avatar alt="User Profile" />
            </IconButton>
            <Menu
              className={classes.profileMenu}
              id="menu-appbar"
              anchorEl={anchorUser}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: "top",
                horizontal: "right",
              }}
              keepMounted
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: "top",
                horizontal: "right",
              }}
              open={Boolean(anchorUser)}
              onClose={handleCloseUserMenu}
            >
              <NavLink
                className={({ isActive }) =>
                  isActive ? classes.activeNavbarStyle : undefined
                }
                to="/"
              >
                Show Profile
              </NavLink>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <NavLink
                    className={({ isActive }) =>
                      isActive ? classes.activeNavbarStyle : undefined
                    }
                    to="my-listings"
                  >
                    My Listings
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>Pages</li>
                <li>Goes</li>
                <li>Here</li>
                <li
                  className={classes.logOutButton}
                  onClick={() => {
                    localStorage.clear();
                    navigate(0);
                  }}
                >
                  Log Out
                </li>
              </ul>
            </Menu>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <NavLink
              className={({ isActive }) =>
                isActive ? classes.activeNavbarStyle : undefined
              }
              to="login"
            >
              Login
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink
              className={({ isActive }) =>
                isActive ? classes.activeNavbarStyle : undefined
              }
              to="register"
            >
              Register
            </NavLink>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );```
````

Comment: This seems more likely a CSS issue with one of the scrolling libraries you are using than it does an issue with routing/navigation.

Comment: Thanks so much for the comment! I'll look into that as soon as I can and let you know if it's fixed.

Comment: Disabling the Parallax library did not work :( - what I also see is that if I open my NavLinks in a new tab, then the scrollbar renders, just like when I refresh the browser. Do you think that the issue might be with caching or something similar in Vite? I recently migrated from CRA to Vite, and while I was using CRA, I never had this issue.